# I pass the key to my component StarRating but when I tried to use route in my other js file, appears undefined

Tags: react-native, routes, undefined

This is my first js file, so basically what I'm trying to do is to pass this _id to the component `StarRatings` to use it there (this is coded on a second file).

**InfoCard.js**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { IconButton, Text, Title } from 'react-native-paper';
import { getExhibitionById } from '../api/exhibitions';
import ModalBody from '../components/ModalBody';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { map, size } from 'lodash';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import StarRatings from './StarRatings';

/**
 * Pantalla que muestra los detalles de una Exhibición.
 * @param {prop} route - Recibe parametros importantes para mostrar en pantalla
 * @param {prop} navigation - Contiene información básica de navegación
 * @param {string} _id - ID asociado a una Exhibición.
 * @property {Object} exhibition - Objeto que contiene la estructura de una Exhibición.
 * @property {function} setExhibition - Método de acceso indirecto para modificar la propieadad exhibition.
 * @property {boolean} visible - Variable auxiliar para controlar la visibilidad de un componente <Modal>.
 * @property {function} setVisible - Método de acceso indirecto para modificar la propieadad visible.
 * @property {function} useEffect - Hook de React que permite realizar tareas asíncronas a la vista.
 * @property {function} useState - Hook de React que permite crear una variable de estado con su método accesor.
 * @property {Promise} getExhibitionById - {@link getExhibitionById} | Promesa que devuelve la información dependiendo la respuesta del servidor.
 * @property {function} size - Función de la librería lodash | Devuelve el tamaño de una colección.
 * @property {function} map - Función de la librería lodash | Crea un arreglo de valores a partir de cada elemento de una colección.
 * @listens {onPress} | El método showModal se dispara cuando ocurre este evento en un componente <ModalButton>.
 * @see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#size
 * @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
 * @see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop/
 * @see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map
 * @return {SafeAreaView} Retorna un componente que contiene maquetada la vista
 */
const InfoCard = ({ route }) => {
  
  const { _id } = route.params;
  console.log(_id);
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [exhibition, setExhibition] = useState(null);

  const showModal = () => setVisible(!visible);

  useEffect(() => {
    getExhibitionById(_id).then((response) => {
      setExhibition(response);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!exhibition) return null;

  const [imageURL] = exhibition.images;
  const [logoURL] = exhibition.sponsorLogo;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <InfoImage path={imageURL} />
        <InfoModal setVisible={setVisible} />
        <InfoTitle exhibition={exhibition} />
        <Text style={styles.overview}>{exhibition.description}</Text>
        {logoURL && <InfoSponsor url={logoURL} />}
        <InfoFooter exhibition={exhibition} />
        <StarRatings
        key={_id}
        />
      </ScrollView>
      <ModalBody
        visible={visible}
        showModal={showModal}
        curiousInfo={exhibition.curiousInfo}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default InfoCard;

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const InfoImage = ({ path }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewPoster}>
      <Image style={styles.poster} source={{ uri: path }} />
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const InfoModal = ({ setVisible }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewModal}>
      <IconButton
        icon="information-variant"
        size={30}
        color="#000"
        style={styles.info}
        onPress={() => setVisible(true)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const InfoTitle = ({ exhibition }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewInfo}>
      <Title style={{ color: '#F29F05', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 23 }}>
        {exhibition.name}
      </Title>
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const InfoSponsor = ({ url }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewSponsor}>
      <Title
        style={{
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: 17,
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          marginHorizontal: 30,
          marginTop: 5,
        }}>
        Patrocina:{' '}
      </Title>
      <Image source={{ uri: url }} style={styles.imgSponsor} />
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const InfoFooter = ({ exhibition }) => {
  const {
    minimumAge,
    maximumAge,
    educationArea,
    duration,
    capacity,
  } = exhibition;
  return (
    <View style={styles.viewFooter}>
      <FooterItem
        title="Educación:"
        desc={educationArea}
        icon="book-open-variant"
      />
      <FooterItem
        title="Edades:"
        desc={`${minimumAge} a ${maximumAge} años`}
        icon="human-male-boy"
      />
      <FooterItem
        title="Duración:"
        desc={duration == 1 ? `${duration} minuto` : `${duration} minutos`}
        icon="clock-time-three-outline"
      />
      <FooterItem
        title="Capacidad:"
        desc={capacity == 1 ? `${capacity} niño` : `${capacity} niños`}
        icon="account-group"
      />
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const FooterItem = ({ title, desc, icon }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <IconButton
        icon={icon}
        size={30}
        color="#F87311"
        style={styles.footerItem}
      />
      <Text style={[styles.textItem, { fontWeight: 'bold' }]}>{title}</Text>
      {Array.isArray(desc) ? (
        map(desc, (d, index) => (
          <Text key={index} style={styles.textItem}>
            {d}
            {index !== size(desc) - 1 && ', '}
          </Text>
        ))
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.textItem}>{desc}</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

/**
 *@ignore
 */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewPoster: {
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 10,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 10,
  },
  poster: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 500,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 30,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 30,
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    marginTop: -40,
    marginRight: 30,
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    borderRadius: 100,
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 0.15,
  },
  viewInfo: {
    marginHorizontal: 30,
  },
  viewRating: {
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  viewModal: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  viewFooter: {
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  footerItem: {
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#F87311',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  textItem: {
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 13,
    color: '#000',
  },
  overview: {
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Bold',
    marginHorizontal: 30,
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'justify',
    color: '#929292',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  imgSponsor: {
    width: 160,
    height: 100,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 4,
    marginBottom: 2,
  },
});
```

This is the second file `StarRatings.js`, here I try to get what's inside the route but the console prints undefined. So basically the logic is A menu > Another menu (here route gets the id) > This info card (uses the id to load the info) and in this same info card is my component that gets undefined.

```js
// React Native Custom Star Rating Bar
// https://aboutreact.com/react-native-custom-star-rating-bar/

// import React in our code
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
/*import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';*/
/**
 * Pantalla que muestra los detalles de una Exhibición.
 * @param {prop} route - Recibe parametros importantes para mostrar en pantalla
 * @param {prop} navigation - Contiene información básica de navegación
 * @param {string} _id - ID asociado a una Exhibición.
 * @property {Object} exhibition - Objeto que contiene la estructura de una Exhibición.
 * @property {function} setExhibition - Método de acceso indirecto para modificar la propieadad exhibition.
 * @property {boolean} visible - Variable auxiliar para controlar la visibilidad de un componente <Modal>.
 * @property {function} setVisible - Método de acceso indirecto para modificar la propieadad visible.
 * @property {function} useEffect - Hook de React que permite realizar tareas asíncronas a la vista.
 * @property {function} useState - Hook de React que permite crear una variable de estado con su método accesor.
 * @property {Promise} getExhibitionById - {@link getExhibitionById} | Promesa que devuelve la información dependiendo la respuesta del servidor.
 * @property {function} size - Función de la librería lodash | Devuelve el tamaño de una colección.
 * @property {function} map - Función de la librería lodash | Crea un arreglo de valores a partir de cada elemento de una colección.
 * @listens {onPress} | El método showModal se dispara cuando ocurre este evento en un componente <ModalButton>.
 * @see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#size
 * @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
 * @see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/route-prop/
 * @see https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map
 * @return {SafeAreaView} Retorna un componente que contiene maquetada la vista
 */


const StarRatings = ({route}) => {
  console.log(route);
  // To set the default Star Selected
  const [defaultRating, setDefaultRating] = useState(2);
  // To set the max number of Stars
  const [maxRating, setMaxRating] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  // Filled Star. You can also give the path from local
  const starImageFilled =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/star_filled.png';
  // Empty Star. You can also give the path from local
  const starImageCorner =
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/star_corner.png';

  const CustomRatingBar = () => {
    
    return (
      
      <View style={styles.customRatingBarStyle}>
        {maxRating.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              activeOpacity={0.7}
              key={item}
              onPress={() => setDefaultRating(item)}>
              <Image
                style={styles.starImageStyle}
                source={
                  item <= defaultRating
                    ? { uri: starImageFilled }
                    : { uri: starImageCorner }
                }
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}>Por favor deja tu reseña de la exhibición</Text>
        {/*View to hold our Stars*/}
        <CustomRatingBar />
        
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

/*
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', defaultRating)
  } catch (e) {
    
  }
}
*/

export default StarRatings;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2',
    padding: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    padding: 8,
    fontSize: 16,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  textStyle: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#000',
    marginTop: 15,
  },
  textStyleSmall: {
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 14,
    color: '#000',
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 15,
    backgroundColor: '#e3001b',
  },
  buttonTextStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'NunitoSans-Bold',
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  customRatingBarStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  starImageStyle: {
    width: 45,
    height: 45,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
  },
});
```

Comment: No one can compile and test this code since there's so many missing pieces. Can you create a [mre] on [snack.expo.dev](https://snack.expo.dev)?

Comment: if you want to get passed 'id' inside of ratingView, get it like this StarRatings = ({key}) => {}

Comment: Yes, the solution was instead of using key as parameter, I used any other word since key is a reserved word " <StarRatings
        id={_id}
        />" . Didn't know it was that quite easy to pass a variable from one js to another.